# Slideshow Shows in Preview Site But Doesn't Show When Uploaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, hosting

I have a JQuery slideshow ([camera.js](http://www.pixedelic.com/plugins/camera/)) on my webpage. When I view the slideshow in the preview viewer, it shows and works perfectly. However, when I upload it to my hosting site, it shows the slideshow, but there are no pictures, as you can see [here](http://pomona-hs.jeffco.k12.co.us/pomona-hs/html/newpomona/index.html).

If someone could let me know what I'm doing wrong, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looking at your site in Chrome I get a load of 404 errors shown in the developer console. Also, 'getAddress()' is being reported as undefined.

Comment: Fixed, but no success. Site can be seen here http://pomonabeta.comeze.com/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got some errors that are probably keeping things from working properly.

1) Javascript: line 3 of getURL.js should have `()` after `getAddress`. (This is probably the main cause.

2) You've got some 404s for the camera.js image assets.

3) Index line 96 "getAddress is not defined". This is a result of 1).

### Update:

It also looks as if you are initializing the plugin before the container exists. You should either put the code in your footer or in a .ready event like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#camera_wrap_3').camera({
        pagination: false,
        thumbnails: false,
    imagePath:'images/camera/'          
    });
});
```

The ready function waits until the page is loaded before executing the code.

Comment: Fixed the getAddress function (site I'm using as test can be viewed here http://pomonabeta.comeze.com/). Still seems not to work, I also don't see any 404 errors. What are the steps you used to obtain these errors?

Comment: To check your errors use Chrome developer tools if you are using Chrome or Firebug in Firefox. Also updated my answer for ya.

Comment: This is a very interesting fix. Added this to the website and the Javascript that wasn't working is now working, including the getURL() (finally). Problem is, as you can see, the slideshow still does not show.

Comment: Also, I know how to get into the Chrome developer tools, but how do I debug websites?

Comment: It's looking at this folder: images/camera/main. Is that where your images are? Also, for errors click on the console button in web developer tools.

Comment: Yes, those are where my two main images are located.

Comment: Okay, it's because your file extensions are capitalized on the actual images and not capitalized in your data-src. I would change your image file extensions to lower case.

Comment: Still does not work. As I said, it works in preview, but not when I upload it.

Comment: Just had a look and your assets are still named with .PNG. Your server doesn't like that and is showing a 404 error.

Comment: YES! It works! Thanks so much man! You really helped a lot. Never would have i thought .PNG was the problem. Once again, thanks, and take my sincere gratitude.